# Using angular.element containing a directive appears to ignore the transcluded content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a directive that I need to dynamically produce:

```
var windowEl = angular.element("<window>Transcuded content....</window");

$compile(windowEl)(scope);

$element.append(windowEl);
```

What happens is the myWindow directive is successfully created and attached to the dom, however the transcluded content is lost. I do have `transclude: true` set in the directive object. Is there something I'm missing here? If not, any ideas on a workaround?

Here's my windowDirective.js

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
  app.directive('window', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,

      templateUrl: 'app/shared/windows/windowView.html',

      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.closeWindow = function () {
          $(".window").hide();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Dynamically generating html in JS is an angular code smell. Unless you have a really good reason to do it (and you might!), I'd recommend that you move this to a proper template and attach the template to a directive.

Comment: Also, can you attach the code for the my-window directive?

Comment: I'm unsure how to accomplish what I'd like within an angular structure. Essentially I need to create an os window style system where as a new window and context can be loaded on the fly. I wouldn't want to use something like ng-repeat for every possible window directive, load context then hide them all and simply show the selected window, that seems counterintuitive to me. It appears that angular wants everything to be in a view then manipulated from there. Is it not possible to add a window view/directive on the fly.. This is actually quite easy to accomplish in Ember. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I actually don't want to produce html on fly, rather nest another directive inside the window directive, however I attempted that to no avail, same issue, angular.element only created the window directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and seems to work check [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AxkTW0?p=preview) in that case i do the same has you, the only difference is that if you are using a directive to inject dynamically your `window` should be:

```
 angular.module('App').directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
      controller: function ($scope,$compile,$element) {
        var windowEl = angular.element("<window>Transcuded content....</window");
        $compile(windowEl)($scope);
        $element.append(windowEl);
      }
    }
  });
```

However just like @[Andrew Eisenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172363/andrew-eisenberg) i don't recommend you to inject dynamically html, probably there is a better approach but we need to understand your scenario better. If doesn't work please update a plunker.